# Odoo not displayed field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I get a problem with displaying custom field in sale order view.

**sale_order.py**

```
...
'typeship' : fields.many2one('vips_shop.delivery',  string="Type delivery", readonly=False),
'usersess' : fields.many2one('vips_vc.session', string="Session customer", readonly=False),
...
```

**sale_order.xml**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_order_usersess_form_view">
    <field name="name">order.usersess</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="client_order_ref" position="after">
            <field name="usersess" string="User Session ID"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_order_typeship_form_view">
    <field name="name">order.typeship</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="client_order_ref" position="after">
            <field name="typeship" string="Type shipping"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

As result i received this: field usersess displayed fine, typeship - not displayed.
Why is it happening? All fields for usersess and typeship is equal.

Comment: why are you having two separate views for showing two fields? Why are you not showing both of them in single inherited view? I think view priority may help you.

Comment: Tnx! It really works

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Hardik Patadia

> why are you having two separate views for showing two fields? Why are
>   you not showing both of them in single inherited view? I think view
>   priority may help you

When I'm showing in single view all displayed fine:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_order_usersess_form_view">
    <field name="name">order.usersess</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="client_order_ref" position="after">
            <field name="usersess" string="User Session ID"/>
            <field name="typeship" string="Type shipping"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```